# How do I find which button the console is referring to in Xcode?

Tags: ios

I'm getting a runtime error:

```
Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x13fe79390> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
```

Since I have thousands of `UIButton`s, is there a quick way to find what does this number `0x13fe79390` correspond to? I know I can `po 0x13fe79390` but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: That isn't the compiler complaining; that's the runtime.

Comment: It's the UIButton, which is connected with a 500 constraint to the bottom of the superview. `Thousands of UIButtons`, what?

Comment: Thanks @LordZsolt, that was just an example though.

Comment: Cant you inspect the button's superview, then get the class who owns that view? Depends on the heirarchy though. You will have to look around in the debug pane

Comment: Use the "Reveal" software. Do it. Buy it. This thing saved me `Thousands of Hours`.

Comment: Thanks @Zil, I now remember a friend of mine also told me about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is for debugging `forUndefinedKey`. First try to add an **All exception breakpoint**. The compiler will stop at where the error happens.

[image]

Also, you can **add a symbolic breakpoint**,like the screenshot I post,then **right click** the breakpoint,selected **edit breakpoint**

[image]

Then it will stop at `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`. You can see the call tree from the screenshot of the left part. Here my error happens at `[ViewController viewDidLoad]`

[image]

Also, you can use the address in LLDB. This is how you instantiate a button object

```
e UIButton * $b = (UIButton*)0x7fb938c64750
```

This is how you print a button's superView information:

```
po [$b superview]
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer my question, I really appreciate you posting this. It'll definitely be helpful!